# "That's a miss" when going back to a list of tagged questions

Tags: discussion, support, bug, tags, new-nav

When I filter questions by a tag, it works fine.

But if I click on a question and then go back, the list of questions shows up for a fraction of a second, and then "That's a miss" appears.

[[Link to screen recording]](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxRMbmixnUEoS3IyclJEZTJxUjQ)

---

Browser used in screen recording was Safari 9.1.2. Tested on Chrome 52 and same thing.

Comment: No repo here. I filtered by tag, selected a question, and went back immediately. I saw nothing wrong (Chrome on Android)

Comment: likewise to what @psubsee2003 said (tested in Chrome 52.0.2743.116, Firefox 48.0.2 and IE11 in Windows 7 SP1). might be good to list what browser, version and OS your using

Comment: @Memor-X Browser used in screen recording was Safari 9.1.2. Tested on Chrome 52.0.2743.116 and same thing.

Comment: @narawagames yeh that's weird. even after clearing my cache and trying again my Chrome isn't doing the same. both browsers still do it for you even now? what OS are you using? (Windows, Android, iOS, whatever the hell Macs)

Comment: @Memor-X The OS I used was Mac OS 10.11.

Comment: I have had this problem this morning using Chrome v53 on Windows 10.